# Is a feedforward box stacked on a dialog a good solution?

Tags: modal-windows, dialog

I'm designing an application where users can add items to a list. When adding a new item a dialog appears to fill out some basic information. Users can cancel/delete this new item by clicking the cross in the upper right hand corner. Before deleting I want to show the users a feedforward dialog asking them if they're sure.

**Is it acceptable to stack this dialog on top of the add item dialog?**

If not, what would be a better solution?

See image below.

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to make the adding inside a dialog box?

Comment: @DimitraMiha Not necessary, but (for now) the best option compared to others. I'm open to suggestions, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When adding a new item a dialog appears to fill out some basic
>   information.*

Firstly, are you sure this is the right way to go? Are you popping up the dialog box every time the user adds a new item? I am sure you understand that that's not a good UX. You need to let the users add all the items they want in their list and then ask them those questions.

Secondly, to answer your question, this is acceptable since it's the best option for you (as you said in your comment), I would suggest you let the user delete that item and give an **undo** button somewhere. Possibly next to the item just deleted. Something like this:

```
You just deleted item XYZ. Undo
```

The undo can be a button with a different shade of color. This will eliminate the popup and maintain the smooth flow.

Apologies if this wasn't helpful.